Ho can I find "offline files" in the terminal (due to fileprovider / OneDrive)?
I've been having trouble with Microsoft OneDrive, which throws up a lot of sync errors and syncs very slowly if at all.
However, despite having selected for the directory at issue "Always Keep On This Device", I'm pretty sure some of the files it has managed to upload are now "offline only".
I'd like a reliable way to search for "offline files" in the terminal. It's a vast directory hierarchy, much too large to search in Finder, and the icons that are supposed to indicate file status in the Finder simply do not appear beside many files.

While not related to using the Terminal, have you tried logging out of OneDrive and then logging back in so that it can re-sync the files/folders?

I did. No luck.
